# Windows phone developement error

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to develop apps for windows phone. For this, I have installed visual studio 2010 in windows 8 machine. After that, I opened visual studio and created new project. But in silverlight option, I did not find "Windows Phone Application" template. 
I searched on google and installed visual studio 2012 express for windows phone by which windows phone 8 sdk is installed. But still I am not getting "Windows Phone Application" template. So what should I do now?

Comment: To create Windows Phone applications in VS2010, you need the WP7 SDK. To create Windows Phone applications in VS2012, you need the WP8 SDK.

Comment: Do you have any other VS version istalled, before installing WP7 or WP8 SDK ?

Answer (score 2):

To create Windows Phone 7 applications in VS2010, I believe you need to install the [Windows Phone 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570). Because you're running Windows 8, I recommend downloading the update for it, too, from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29233).

The template should be visible in VS2012, though, if you've installed the WP8 SDK, so I'm not sure why you can't see them in that.

Comment: I tried to install windows phone 7 sdk. but it gave me error of compatibility issue..so i installed windows phone 8 sdk...but it did not work

Comment: In what way did it not work? If you open VS2012, what templates are available?